# Why I have "Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System [...]" into the logcat when my app has nothing to do with that?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I didn't found any reference on-line. Just some logcat with the same line, apparently from Android 4.2+ and possibly from CyanogenMod devices, like the GT-I9100 I own.

Developing my android App in Eclipse, I keep getting this line, once in a while, into the LogCat view, auto-filtered with my app's package name. So it seems to be coming from, or at least caused by, my app.

The complete line is: `Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value`

The app doesn't have nothing to do with such Android global setting.

Any hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any third-party libraries that might be accessing this?

Comment: Well, thanks. I didn't think about them. Could be BugSense checking for connections (just a thought). I'll try commenting out the calls to this library to see what happens.

Comment: It's not BugSense: the line has spawned again.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It was the Picasso library.

And the calls generating the warning (for API level > 17) are:

```
import static android.provider.Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON;
```

and

```
static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {
  ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
  return Settings.System.getInt(contentResolver, AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
}
```

See docs ref:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#AIRPLANE_MODE_ON

Comment: Glad you figured it out - you can accept your own answer for reputation.

Comment: @dentex - I've got the same problem. I just wonder; what did you do to solve this? Where did you find these lines? In the Picasso source? And did you remove those lines? Doesn't that break anything? Any more information on this would be very welcome!

Comment: @kramer65: I just ignore the warning. It makes no harm. Yes it's from the Picasso source. I went to find the link to this issue: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/274 but noticed you already found it ;)

Comment: Nice catch. Thanks for sharing the root cause.