# Easiest way to use Picasso in notification (icon)

Tags: android, multithreading, android-notifications, picasso

I'm looking for an easy way to use Picasso to load a noticiation icon (which is a URL on a remote webpage). In a previous version of the app I'm working on this code seemed to work:

```
        Bitmap speakerPic = null;
        try {
            speakerPic = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        return Picasso.with(c).load(session.getSpeaker().getPhotoUrl()).get();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute().get(1500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (speakerPic != null) {
            builder.setLargeIcon(speakerPic);
        } else {
            builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        }
```

But now I get an TimeOutException every time (and I fallback to a default icon in my res folder). I have to use this AsyncTask because Picasso (/network) may not happen on the UI thread. (although I'm blocking the UI thread for 1.5sec here..).

I know Picasso can handle remoteviews, but I don't want to use a custom view for my notificiation. Also I couldn't find a way to get the RemoteView for the NoticifationIcon.

Is there a way to set the icon of my notification simply using Picasso?

Comment: Hey Pieter, did you figure this out?

Comment: @KarimVarela yes, see my answer here below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33670047/1534666

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'll answer the question myself because I've found a decent way, using Picasso and RemoteViews. Tested and working with Picasso 2.5.2 :

```
// Default stuff; making and showing notification
final Context context = getApplicationContext();
final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
final Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // Needed for the notification to work/show!!
        .setContentTitle("Title of notification")
        .setContentText("This is the description of the notification")
        // Uncomment if you want to load a big picture
        //.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle())
        .build();
final int notifId = 1337;
notificationManager.notify(notifId, notification);

// Get RemoteView and id's needed
final RemoteViews contentView = notification.contentView;
final int iconId = android.R.id.icon;

// Uncomment for BigPictureStyle, Requires API 16!
//final RemoteViews bigContentView = notification.bigContentView;
//final int bigIconId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/big_picture", null, null);

// Use Picasso with RemoteViews to load image into a notification
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png").into(contentView, iconId, notifId, notification);

// Uncomment for BigPictureStyle
//Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png").into(bigContentView, iconId, notifId, notification);
//Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png").into(bigContentView, bigIconId, notifId, notification);
```

Comment: This doesnt work, it gives error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method call should happen from the main thread.

Comment: Not working if called from a service, because it has to run on UI thread.
Also Notification.contentView is deprecated and can return null on Nougat.

Comment: Its fine in Activity. Why in Service doesnt work.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest a simplest way to integrate a remote picture inside your notification as large icon with Picasso.

```
// your notification builder
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

String picture = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png"; 
Bitmap bmp = Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(picture).get();

notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(bmp);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Picasso.wi.....get() is a synchronous call. It will block the current thread -> make sure you are on a working thread, otherwise the UI of your application will freeze.

Comment: No way, if the Picasso can't load, after 5 sec, it will crash for the foreground service

Comment: short and simple the best solution!

Comment: @AliAlaoi After image loaded, then notify the notification to update

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why your code is not working but its compiling fine for me, tested on API level 21 and Android Studio.

I made a few changes to fit my needs, e.g. removed the time delay.

The only noticeable differences is the below output in my logcat:

```
Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
```

which is normal based on the links: [this](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/274) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164389/why-i-have-setting-airplane-mode-on-has-moved-from-android-provider-settings-sy)

And my updated code is:

```
    Bitmap contactPic = null;

    final String getOnlinePic = GET_AVATAR;

    try {
        contactPic = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    return Picasso.with(ctx).load(getOnlinePic)
                    .resize(200, 200)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_action_user_purple_light)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_action_user_purple_light)
                    .get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (contactPic != null) {
        builder.setLargeIcon(contactPic);
    } else {
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_action_user_purple_light));
    }
```

Comment: The problem is not that the code won't compile, but that the online image doesn't get loaded... It always falls back to the 'default' icon (the AsyncTask returns a null Bitmap).

The real question is how to correctly use Butterknife to successfully load an online image into a notification.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to wait until Picasso fetches the image before sending the notification, one solution is to send the notification **twice with the same id**, so that the `NotificationManager` will update the existing notification the second time it's being sent.

In practice, the first time, use a placeholder for `setLargeIcon()`, and the second time, use the `Bitmap` you got from a Picasso `Target`.

For instance, from your `Activity`:

```
final Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
final int id = 0; // change this w/ your notification id
Bitmap placeholder = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.your_placeholder_icon);
builder.setContentTitle(title)
       .yourFavoriteBuilderMethods(...)
       .setLargeIcon(placeholder)
       .setDefaults(0); // so that it doesn't ring twice
// mTarget should an instance variable of your class so it doesn't get GC'ed
mTarget = new Target() { 
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        builder.setLargeIcon(bitmap)
               .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
       // send the notification again to update it w/ the right image
       ((NotificationManager) (getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)))
          .notify(id, builder.build());
                }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {}

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {}                   
    };

Picasso.with(this).load(your_image_url_here).into(mTarget);

// send notification for the first time here, w/ placeholder:                
((NotificationManager) (getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)))
    .notify(id, builder.build());
```

Since Picasso will need to access the internet, don't forget to set the right permission in your manifest for this to work:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: What if the user already dismissed the notification? You would have to figure out if the notification is still shown before you notify again.

Answer (score 0):

Image loading code using Picaso 2.5.2 starts in middle of this method,besides that all stuff is simple notification code, just copy and paste ,replace "image_url" with actual image url.

```
            private Notification notification;
               public  void genrateNewsNotification(String title, final int id) {
                    try {
                        final Context context=GcmService.this;
                        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
                        final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        notificationManager.cancel(id);
                        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);

                        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
                        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
                        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
                        final PendingIntent contentIntent =
                                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                                        id,
                                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                                );
                        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
                        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Custom Notification");
                        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
                        mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
                        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                        if (currentapiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.launch_lolipop);
                        } else {
                            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.launcher_icon);
                        }
                        mBuilder.setContentText(title);
                        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
                        notification= mBuilder.build();

        // image code starts from here 

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                            try{
                                Picasso.with(context).load("image_url")
                                        .into(target);
                                notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e){
            // notification without image in case of Exception
                                notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
                            }

                        }else{
                            notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }



            **// main stuff goes here ,it is an inner class**

               private Target target = new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                        if (bitmap != null) {
                            RemoteViews views;
                            views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
                            views.setTextViewText(R.id.title,  "Daily Notification");
                            views.setTextColor(R.id.title,getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                            views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.big_picture,  bitmap);
                            views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.big_icon, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.launcher_icon));

                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                                notification.bigContentView = views;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        Log.i("errorDrawable","errorDrawable");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                    }


                };
```