# Error on calling Microsoft Azure API

Tags: android, azure

String api = "notificationregistration?handle="+libFile.getDeviceToken();

```
mClient.invokeApi(api, null, "POST", null, new ApiJsonOperationCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(JsonElement jsonElement, Exception e, ServiceFilterResponse serviceFilterResponse)
    {
        if(e == null)
        {
            try
            {
                String registrationId = jsonElement.toString().replaceAll("\"","");

                if(AppConstants.DEBUG) Log.v(AppConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "NOTIFICATION REGISTRATION ID : "+registrationId);
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Error:

```
Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.      
  at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.MobileServiceConnection$1.onNext(MobileServiceConnection.java:128)      
  at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient$15.handleRequest(MobileServiceClient.java:1499)      
  at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.MobileServiceConnection.start(MobileServiceConnection.java:113)      
  at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestAsyncTask.java:78)      
  at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestAsyncTask.java:35)      
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)      
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)      
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)      
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)      
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: It just seems to be the content of error stack from logcat, that's unclear for resolving your issue. Please post more details for improving content,such as what Azure API you called, some key codes & description, your question, etc.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT Please check updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was any obvious issue in your code. Just according to the error information, it seems to be enabled airplane mode on Android device. Was it? Please check and try again.

Or some third party libraries might cause the issue, like the other SO thread  [Why I have "Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System [...]" into the logcat when my app has nothing to do with that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164389/why-i-have-setting-airplane-mode-on-has-moved-from-android-provider-settings-sy) made.